# Overload selection with parameter pack and universal references

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I've been trying to use perfect forwarding with a parameter pack that I recursively unpack, and that made me realize I don't really understand the rules that govern how overloads for a given function are selected in the presence of universal references.

My confusion was motivated by some code similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
void write(const T& data)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(const T& data)" << std::endl;
}

template<class T, class ...U>
void write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  int j = 0;
  write(j);
  return 0;
}
```

When run, the `void write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)` overload is selected, but if I change the signature of `void write(const T& data)` to `void write(const T data)`, `void write(T& data)`, or `void write(T data)` then that function is called.

Why is the `void write(const T& data)` overload not selected but `void write(const T data)`, `void write(T& data)`, or `void write(T data)` are?

Edit: I originally though that the issue may have been related to use of `std::forward`; however it appears to be more a result of the universal references. My original example is below:

```
#include <iostream>

void write()
{
  std::cout << "Writing nothing" << std::endl;
}

void write(const char* data)
{
  std::cout << "Writing const char*: " << data << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void write(const T& data)
{
  std::cout << "Writing generic: " << data << std::endl;
}

template<class T, class ...U>
void write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)
{
  write(std::forward<T>(obj));
  write(std::forward<U>(objs)... );
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  int j = 0;
  write("a", j);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question might be a bit complicated. I'll try to be simpler.

It appears that, after reference collpasing, the candidates for overload resolutions are `write(const T&)` and `write(T&)`, both with `T = int` and the second one has `U... = (none)`. This way, the latter one is picked and the forwarding funtion is called again.

Comment: Downvoter, can you please tell me why? I'm curious, too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [iBug's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397485/5376789), it is a special rule that `T&` beats `const T&` for lvalue argument of type `T`. For other cases (`const T`, `T&`, `T`) both implicit conversion sequences are exact matches (`T -> const T` is qualification adjustment, which is also an exact match) thus neither beats the other, and the first `write` is more specialized than the second one, so the first one is chosen.